# Fatal error: attempt to evaluate editor placeholder: file MyPlayground.playground,

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

Hello before my xcode wasn't showing anything on the sidebar or in the result area suddenly it started showing and i wrote a small piece of code and getting this error "Fatal error: attempt to evaluate editor placeholder: file MyPlayground.playground"

Following is my code

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
func calcBmi(weight : Double, height : Double) -> Double{
    let BMI = weight/pow(height,2)
    return BMI
}
var bmiResutl = calcBmi(weight: 60, height: 1.83)
print(bmiResutl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading your file and see if that works for you. (Close xCode and load your file again)

Answer (score 0):

Using your code provides this result at my end:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcgD5.png)